# Align bottom using mdframed

Tags: vertical-alignment, mdframed

I'm using [mdframed](https://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed?lang=en) to create a box around two lines of text so that I can insert a colored left border. Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{mdframed}

\newmdenv[topline=false,rightline=false,bottomline=false,linewidth=2pt]{leftbot}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{15pt}


\newcommand{\leftborder}[1]{
    \begin{leftbot}
        {
            \fontsize{11pt}{0pt}
            \selectfont
            \MakeUppercase{Use Cases}
            \par
        }
        { % Title
            \fontsize{25pt}{25pt}
            \selectfont
            \textbf{#1}
        }
    \end{leftbot}
}

\begin{document}
    \leftborder{Internet of Things}
\end{document}
```

The result is actually not bad at all:

[image]

But it's slightly different from what I want:

[image]

Nevermind the line color and the font, I already managed those two. The problem is how the text is aligned with respect to the border. In my version, the text appears to be vertically centered, but the design version is aligned to the bottom. How can I do that?

Comment: Please note that your `\fontsize{25pt}{25pt}` is not really well chosen, nor is `\fontsize{11pt}{0pt}`

Comment: I know, but this is never supposed to span multiple lines, this actually came from design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `innerbottommargin` to `0pt` or even a negative value, say, `1ex`. `0pt` will place the descdender of `g` on the bottom line.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{mdframed}

\newmdenv[topline=false,innerbottommargin=-1ex,rightline=false,bottomline=false,linewidth=2pt]{leftbot}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{15pt}


\newcommand{\leftborder}[1]{
    \begin{leftbot}
        {
            \fontsize{11pt}{0pt}
            \selectfont
            \MakeUppercase{Use Cases}
            \par
        }
        { % Title
            \fontsize{25pt}{25pt}
            \selectfont
            \textbf{#1}
        }
    \end{leftbot}
}

\begin{document}
    \leftborder{Internet of Things}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 always for the you excellent answer. Is it arrived my upvpte?

Comment: @Christian, this does work for the text "Internet of Things", but the space between the two lines grew instead of bringing "USE CASES" down as well. Would you know a fix for that?

Comment: (Although, I might just ask the designer if this is OK. But that will have to wait until Monday...)

Comment: @AndréFratelli: `mdframed` offers `innertopmargin` as option as well.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer great, I'll give it a go!